# Running A Python Program Created With The Python-IDLE In the Windows command prompt using a batch file ,gives me an error message

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a program that I coded in the Python-IDLE in the command prompt of windows. So I watched a video on Youtube which showed me that, but it did not work. From the video I learned how to run IDLE code using a batch file. So I created a batch file in the Python IDLE and put it in the same folder in which I put the program I created with the Python IDLE. Then I used the windows (Run) command to run the batch file and the command prompt gave me an error message.

I have already tried not using the windows run command, (Win+R), but searching the command prompt in the windows search bar and then running the program which I created in the Python_IDLE in the Command Prompt, and that gave me the exact same error message.

This is the program I tried to run:

```
name = input('Input your name: ')
age = input('Input your birth year: ')
print(f'Hello {name}, I know you are {age} years old')
```

This is the error message I got (in the command prompt):

```
no such file or directory
```

This is what I wrote in the Python-IDLE to create the batch file:

```
@py C:\Users\Angelo Hoft\PyProjects\Greeting.py %*
@pause
```

And this is the command I entered in the windows (Run) tab:

```
C:\Users\Angelo Hoft\PyProjects\hello.bat
```

*`Angelo Hoft` is the user of the computer I am using, `PyProjects` is the folder in which I stored the batch file and the Python-IDLE Program I am trying to run in the command prompt*

But I just want my program to ask the user for input and then make a sentence out of it which contains the user's name and age.

Comment: It would certainly help matters were you to show use the content of the [tag:batch-file], the command you entered in the run box, and/or the Command Prompt window.

Comment: I updated it. I hope this helps you in answering my question @Compo

Comment: There is no such thing as 'IDLE code'.  The code you wrote with the IDLE editor is pure Python, and once you saved it, it is irrelevant what editor you used to write it.  So the question is about  Python on Windows, not about IDLE. `no such file or directory` comes from the Windows command processor, not python.  User 'magoo' addressed that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"C:\Users\Angelo Hoft\PyProjects\hello.bat"` as your command. Since the command contains a space, `cmd` will interpret the command you entered as `C:\Users\Angelo` with an argument of `Hoft\PyProjects\hello.bat`. Since `C:\Users\Angelo` is not an executable file, `cmd` duly reports this. Quoting the command tells `cmd` that the space is part of the string, not a separator between strings.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question @Magoo . But how do i fix that problem now

Comment: The problem appeared to be `no such file or directory` when running `hello.bat`. Perhaps changing `@py C:\Users\Angelo Hoft\PyProjects\Greeting.py %*` to `@py "C:\Users\Angelo Hoft\PyProjects\Greeting.py" %*` may cure the other problem.

Comment: It actually worked!!  Many thanks for the pro called @Magoo for helping me out.